# Problem image, How to have the image above automatically adjust when minimize a window. Also, any recommendation

Tags: html, css, image, menu, nav

How to adjust image when window is minimize. Also, any recommendation to the text on top of the image. same thing with the image it doesn't adjust when window is minimize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>My Webpage</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
     <img src="headerpunk2.jpg" alt="Headerimg" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="top-left">Hi, I'm Paulo</div>
    </div>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#works">Works</a> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += "responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls, show your html?

Comment: brother how can I attach the code here?

Comment: You need to **Edit** your question.